# Error installing sveltekit app after upgrading Node to latest version

Tags: node.js, npm, svelte, sveltekit

I recently upgraded node to the latest version (v16.15.1). After upgrading, I started a new sveltekit site using the following command:

```
npm init svelte my-app
```

I CD'd into my-app and ran npm install and get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /Users/henken/Sites/my-app
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c svelte-kit sync
npm ERR! sh: svelte-kit: command not found
```

I've created many sveltekit apps using these exact steps without any issues until today after upgrading node. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

Remove the my-app folder and run:

```
npm init svelte@latest my-app
```

The `@latest` makes sure that npm uses latest version of the create-svelte package.
The version you've got cached locally could be incompatible with the current version of SvelteKit.

Alternative things to try:

- Reboot PC (removes environment settings that could point to previous node installation)
- Upgrade npm to latest version

Comment: I still get the same error in my original post when I CD into the directory and perform an npm install.

Comment: :(  the error indicates that it has trouble executing the svelte-kit script, you mentioned upgrading node, is "/usr/bin/env node" still working?